# What happen to existing server queries when pushing new Rails code to Heroku or putting it in maintenance mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This page http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode doesn't give any indication.
Server queries to Heroku could run up to 30 seconds before they got terminated forcefully. So I am wondering what would happen if I push new code to the busy server, or set it to be in Maintenance mode?  Would the existing queries just stopped?  What if it is writing to a database, etc?  Would it leave my data in a corrupted state?

Is there a correct way to let Rails app  to shut down gracefully (finishing existing queries but not accepting any new one), so that I can upgrade the server code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you put your app in maintenance mode you are not changing your codebase at all. It's a front-end configuration.

It means, if a query was sent to the database, the database won't be stopped and the query will be executed. The connections are not dropped when you switch to maintenance mode.